# unable to select a sql variable

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to create one dynamic query and execute it, in this query, name of the table should change on run time, the pattern of the name of the table that should change on run time is "D_M". Please see the code for further clarification.

Following is the code that I'm unable to execute:

```
DECLARE @MyCursor 
CURSOR,@ChannelName NVARCHAR(max),@ChannelNumber NVARCHAR(max),@sqlstring NVARCHAR(max);BEGIN 
    SET @MyCursor = 
    CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT mirthdb.dbo.channel.NAME, 
             mirthdb.dbo.d_channels.local_channel_id 
      FROM   mirthdb.dbo.d_channels, 
             mirthdb.dbo.channel 
      WHERE  mirthdb.dbo.channel.id = mirthdb.dbo.d_channels.channel_id 
      AND    mirthdb.dbo.channel.NAME LIKE '0%' 
OPEN @MyCursor 
FETCH next 
FROM  @MyCursor 
INTO  @ChannelName, 
      @ChannelNumber; 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
BEGIN 
  SET @sqlstring = 'select' +(@ChannelName), 
    ('select count(*) from mirthdb.dbo.D_M'+@ChannelNumber) 
  EXEC(@sqlstring) 
  --print @ChannelNumber 
  FETCH next 
  FROM  @MyCursor 
  INTO  @ChannelName, 
        @ChannelNumber 
END 
CLOSE @MyCursor; 
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor; 
END;
```

I'm trying to achieve the following result set:
Channel Name : Number of Messages Received
test_name1   : 2
test_name2   : 4
test_name3   : 0

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Hi jarlh, actually, the structure of database is a little complicated, I get the name of the channel from one table and the number of records received for that particular channel comes from the other tables, but I'll try to figure out if joins can be helpful in my situation.